# Why doesn't my Kedro starter prompt for input?

Tags: python, reusability, kedro

I would like to create my own Kedro starter. I have tried to replicate the relevant portions of the pandas iris starter. I have a `cookiecutter.json` file with what I believe are appropriate mappings, and I have changed the repo and package directory names as well as any references to Kedro version such that they work with cookie cutter.

I am able to generate a new project from my starter with `kedro new --starter=path/to/my/starter`. **However, the newly created project uses the default values for the project, package, and repo names, without prompting me for any input in the terminal**.

Have I misconfigured something? How can I create a starter that will prompt users to override the defaults when creating new projects?

Here are the contents of `cookiecutter.json` in the top directory of my starter project:

```
{
    "project_name": "default",
    "repo_name": "{{ cookiecutter.project_name }}",
    "python_package": "{{ cookiecutter.repo_name }}",
    "kedro_version": "{{ cookiecutter.kedro_version }}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be missing `prompts.yml`
https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/blob/main/kedro/templates/project/prompts.yml

Full instructions can be found here:
https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/07_extend_kedro/05_create_kedro_starters.html

Comment: I'll give this a shot and accept it if it works. Thanks! I was following a 3rd party example that didn't mention this.

Comment: Do you know where `prompts.yml` is supposed to go? I assume the top level directory along with `cookiecutter.yml`, but the documentation doesn't specify, and I don't see any such file in the pandas iris starter: https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro-starter-pandas-iris

Comment: I got it working by placing `prompts.yml` in the top level directory of my starter. I'll accept this answer. I'm confused as to how my clone of the pandas iris starter works seemingly without a `prompts.yml`, but I'll leave that for another question. Thank you!